# When I press I to activate the Insert Keyframe Menu (in the 3d-view/pose mode) the menu doesn't show up

Tags: animation

When I press I to activate the Insert Keyframe Menu (in the 3d-view/pose mode) the menu doesn't show up

Screenshot:
[image]